# Opening Google settings on Android 6+ programmatically

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a shortcut in my app for opening Google settings (or even better, for submenu "Ads"). While this is possible in Android version up to 5.1.1 by using the code

```
public void openGsettings(View view){
    Intent googleSettings = new Intent();
    googleSettings.setPackage("com.google.android.gms");
    googleSettings.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    startActivity(googleSettings);
}
```

and calling it on click, this doesn't really work on Android 6.0 and later as it's not a separate "app" anymore and is located in the system settings instead, so my app just crashes when I press the button.

I know it is possible as I've seen it in another app, but I can't figure out what should I call. Looked through Google documentation and there doesn't seem to be an action for this part of the settings either.

Comment: Do you recall which app you have seen it in?

Comment: Nah, not really, it was some kind of toolkit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Co-worker gave me an answer, so I'm sharing it for anyone else that needs it (this one points to "Ads" section specifically):

```
String action = "com.google.android.gms.settings.ADS_PRIVACY";
    startActivity(new Intent(action));
```

Comment: Well it worked for ads, but how about account/profile settings?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the system-level intents provided by the [`android.provider.Settings`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html) class. All you have to do is provide the `ACTION_SETTINGS` string to your `Intent`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

You can also provide any one of the other `ACTION` strings to your intent to jump to a specific category with settings.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough, I want to open Google settings, not Android settings. Google settings are a submenu within Android settings in Android 6.0 and later.

Comment: @bacje16 Ah, sorry I missed that. I haven't found a solution yet, but I will update if I find one.